# how could I make an app with hidden icon?

Tags: android

I looking for resource that i could hide my icon app.how i could do that?
i used this before but it didn't worked.

```js
try{
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

so could you tell me another way or if it works explain me completly please
I'm using android studio

Comment: remove the launcher intent filer from your activity in manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hide icon:**

```
 ComponentName nm = new ComponentName(
                    getPackageName(),
                    getPackageName() + ".yourLuncherActivity");
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    nm,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

**Show icon:**

```
  ComponentName nm = new ComponentName(
                getPackageName(),
                getPackageName() + ".yourLuncherActivity");
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        pm = getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                nm,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: just call this code when you need to hide and show app icon